# Composer installing: the json extension is missing

Tags: php, json, linux, composer-php

I wrote in Linux Terminal: 
`curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`
It said:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env php
Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

The json extension is missing.
Install it or recompile php without --disable-json
```

I did this:  `apt-get install php5-json`
So, I think, it's installed. But the strange thing is, when I write `php -m`
It gives me a list without json:

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
date
dba
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
hash
iconv
libxml
mbstring
mhash
openssl
pcntl
pcre
Phar
posix
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

And when I write  `php5-fpm -m`
It sends this:

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
cgi-fcgi
Core
ctype
curl
date
dba
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
mysqli
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

What am I doing wrong? I haven't found the solution at GitHub and Google

Comment: Silly question: did you restart the server, didn't you?

Comment: Yes, I did. Unfortunately, it didn't help

Answer (score 10):

I encountered the same error, but the difference was that when I ran `php -m` the `json` module was not listed, so I just installed json PHP module using the command below:

```
sudo yum install php-json
```

the error was fixed and I was able to install composer. I was using CentOS 8 stream, PHP7.2.

Answer (score 7):

You probably need to enable the extension in your `php.ini` file. To find out where that is for command line PHP, do

```
php --ini
```

You should see a line like

> Loaded Configuration File: /path/to/php.ini

Open that file and look for `extension=json.so`. If it's there, uncomment it. If not, add it in. Now you should see `json` listed when you do `php -m` and composer should work.

Comment: In my case the command line php executable I was running was apparently NOT the one I thought -- I had just installed PHP on Windows and was running the command from cygwin, where an older version of PHP was also installed.

Comment: This doesn't apply in PHP 7.

Answer (score 3):

Bug php not load extension install

create file php.ini

```
# /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/php.ini
extension=json.so
extension=phar.so
extension=iconv.so
```

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu 14.04 for me, I found that the default permissions for the php.ini file /etc/php5/cli/ restrict the file to Root user only, so if you run:

```
php -m
```

as non-root, you get far fewer modules than if you run
    sudo php -m

The fix for this was for me to perform:

```
sudo chmod a+rx /etc/php5/cli/* -R
```

which grants read and execute permissions for that folder and it's contents to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

On Centos 8 with PHP 7.2, after comprehensive research, I have concluded that the only solid way to fix it is reinstalling PHP with its newest version. (7.4 was the latest version for me) Here you can find others who share the same conclusion;
[laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/error-json-extension-missing-from-php-72)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the :-

sudo apt-get install php-json

command.
and correct the directory.
so your error will resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $client->transfers->create(
    [
        "targetAccount" => "account id",
        "quoteUuid" => "generated quote id",
        "customerTransactionId" => "transaction id",
        "details" => [
            "reference" => "Company X",
            "transferPurpose"=> "verification.transfers.purpose.pay.bills",
            "sourceOfFunds"=> "verification.source.of.funds.other"
        ]
    ]
);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).